# Is $\{]a,b]:a\in\Bbb R\}$ a system of neighbourhood in the topology on $\Bbb R$ generated by $\{]a,b]:a,b\in\Bbb R\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

If $\mathcal{B}=\{]a,b]:a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is a basis for a topological space $(\mathbb{R},\sigma)$, how can I prove that $\mathcal{W}_{b}=\{]a,b]:a\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is a system of neighborhoods of $b$?

I say:

Let $V$ be a neighborhood of $b$, As $\mathcal{B},$  is a basis then $]a,b]$ is an open containig $b$ so it is include in $V$ then $\mathcal{W}_b$ is a system of neighborhood, is it right?

Comment: Unless you're paying for internet by the letter, why would you write "ngbh"?

Comment: I edited my message, What do you think about my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ be a neighbourhood of $b$. Then there is some basic neighbourhood $(a',b'] \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $b \in (a', b'] \subseteq V$ (we cannot assume a priori that $b$ is the right side limit). But then also $b \in (a',b] \subseteq (a',b'] \subseteq V$ (as $b \leq b'$) and we have $(a',b] \in \mathcal{W}_b$ inside $V$ as required.

Comment: Tank you please can we say that the space is hossdorff and sepable?

Comment: @Vrouvrou Yes, the space with that base is Hausdorff and separable: if $x < y$ note that $(x-1,x]$ and $(x,y]$ are disjoint neighbourhoods of $x$ and $y$. And $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense as it intersects all base elements.